# Style hover on mapped array using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to style the `ListItem` on hover, but the problem is that the list is being mapped over to create multiple list items. When I change the hover style it changes the style for all list items when being hovered. How do I target just one element? Below is the code.
I am trying to style the `prop.icon` and `ListItemText` when they are hovered.

**Sidebar.js**

```js
var links = (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      {routes.map((prop, key) => {
    

        if (prop.path === "/login") {
          return;
          
        }

        return (
          <NavLink
            to={prop.layout + prop.path}
            className={classes.item}
            activeClassName="active"
            key={key}
          >
            
            <ListItem button className={classes.itemLink} onMouseEnter={MouseEnter} onMouseLeave={MouseLeave}>
            <prop.icon
                className={classNames(classes.itemIcon)}
              />
             
              <ListItemText
                primary={prop.name}
                className={classNames(classes.itemText)}
                disableTypography={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          </NavLink>
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
```

**MouseEnter & MouseLeave**

```js
  const MouseEnter = (e) => {
    
    setHovered(true);
  }
  const MouseLeave = (e) => {
    setHovered(false);
  }
```

Comment: Please post MouseEnter and mouseLeave function

Comment: why don't you use css for this?

Comment: What would the css look like? IDK how CSS would work when I need to target one element in a mapped array.

Comment: @AS10 in CSS you just need to refer using `:hover`. It will do all the same what you're trying to achieve with JS but simpler.

Comment: @AS10 please accept an answer to close this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the active index in the array worked for me besides using boolean values.
**sidebar.js**

```js
 const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(-1);

  const MouseEnter = (index) => {
    setHovered(index);
  }
  const MouseLeave = () => {
    setHovered(-1);
  }
  
  
  var links = (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      {routes.map((prop, index, key ) => {
    

        if (prop.path === "/login") {
          return;
          
        }

        return (
          <NavLink
            to={prop.layout + prop.path}
            className={classes.item}
            activeClassName="active"
            key={key}
          >
            
            <ListItem button className={hovered === index ? 'hoverLinear' : classes.itemContainer} onMouseEnter={() => MouseEnter(index)} onMouseLeave={MouseLeave}>
            <prop.icon
              
                className={classNames(classes.itemIcon)}
                 style={hovered === index ? {color: 'white'} : {color: "#8B2CF5"}}
              />
              <ListItemText
                primary={prop.name}
                className={classNames(classes.itemText, ' mx-10')}
                style={hovered === index ? {color: 'white'} : {color: "#3A448E"}}
                disableTypography={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          </NavLink>
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS it would be as simple as that:

```css
.list-item:hover{
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}



/* just for decoration, you don't need the code below*/

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>


<ul >
  <li class="list-item" >
      <span  >&#9824; </span>spades
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
      <span  >&#9827; </span>clubs
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
      <span  >&#9830; </span>dimonds
  </li>
</ul>
```

or with your code:

```
//links.css
.list-item:hover{
  background-color:red;
}

//links.js
import "./links.css"

var links = (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      {routes.map((prop, key) => {


        if (prop.path === "/login") {
          return;

        }

        return (
            <NavLink
                to={prop.layout + prop.path}
                className={classes.item}
                activeClassName="active"
                key={key}
            >

              <ListItem button className={classes.itemLink + " list-item"} onMouseEnter={MouseEnter} onMouseLeave={MouseLeave}>
                <prop.icon
                    className={classNames(classes.itemIcon)}
                />

                <ListItemText
                    primary={prop.name}
                    className={classNames(classes.itemText)}
                    disableTypography={true}
                />
              </ListItem>
            </NavLink>
        );
      })}
    </List>
);
```

Comment: I appreciate the code, but that doesnt work. The background of listItem should be purple while the icon and listItemText should be white on hover. The problem is this is a mapped array so if I apply a hover color to prop.icon whenever I hover any icon it'll change the color to what I set the hover color to.

Comment: @AS10 well of course you have to elaborate on it. I was just trying to demonstrate the basic concept. Add a class to the element you would like to style and then use the `:hover` pseudoselector to style it. If you need an elaborated example, then provide a codesandbox. Right now I don't know what your icon is for example.

However i adjusted my example a bit to fit your comment.